# is.character returns TRUE in apply when it's factor

Tags: r, character, apply

I have the next dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Region = c("ES", "ES", "FRA", "FRA"), 
             Amount = c(1000,1200, 1100, 900))
```

Whose structure is:

```
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
$ Region: chr  "ES" "ES" "FRA" "FRA"
$ Amount: num  1000 1200 1100 900
```

If I use the function `is.character()` for example on `df$Region` I get `FALSE`, but if I use the same function on `apply()` I get `TRUE`, even on the second column which is a number.

Code used:

```
apply(df, 2, is.character) 

Region Amount 
  TRUE   TRUE
```

I don't understand why this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of `apply` says:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.

And the result of `as.matrix(df)` is:

```
> as.matrix(df)
     Region Amount
[1,] "ES"   "1000"
[2,] "ES"   "1200"
[3,] "FRA"  "1100"
[4,] "FRA"  " 900"
```

as the documentation for `as.matrix` states:

> as.matrix is a generic function. The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, applying as.vector to factors and format to other non-character columns.

When using `lapply`, which works on `data.frame` columns without converting to matrix, you get the correct result:

```
> lapply(df, is.character)
$Region
[1] FALSE

$Amount
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

The apply family can be somewhat confusing.

You can use `map` the package `purrr` from the `tidyverse` to iterate.

Here I use `map_df` to return a data frame.

```r
df <- data.frame(Region = c("ES", "ES", "FRA", "FRA"), 
                 Amount = c(1000,1200, 1100, 900))

purrr::map_df(.x = df, .f = is.character)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Region Amount
#>   <lgl>  <lgl> 
#> 1 F      F
```

You can read more about `purrr` [here](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/).